# Display result from loop tables (oracle, pl/sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql, oracle12c

I'm try to loop some tables and run select as below:

```
set serveroutput on
declare

type tables_names is table of varchar2(30);
type selectTable is table of varchar2(30);

tName tables_names;
sTableName selectTable;

begin;

tName := tables_names('PERIOD','SETTING','RAP','LOG');
sTableName := selectTable('m_table1','m_table2','m_table3','m_table4','m_table5');    

    for i in 1..tName.count loop
        for j in 1..sTableName.count loop

               select col10, count(*) from user.sTableName(j) 
               where table_name = tName(i) group by col10;            

        end loop;
    end loop;

end;
```

I got error:PL/SQL: ORA-00933.

Can you please tell me how can I correctly run PL/SQL procedure to have displayed result from my select?

**UPDATE**: looking result

[image]

Normally, to get this I need to run below select's:

```
select column_name, 
count(*) as countColumn
from user.m_table1 where table_name = 'PERIOD' group by column_name;

select column_name, 
count(*) as countColumn
from user.m_table2 where table_name = 'PERIOD' group by column_name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle complains (ORA-00933) that command isn't properly ended. That's probably because of a semi-colon behind the BEGIN; also, you lack the INTO clause.

I'm not sure what PERIOD, SETTING, ... are opposed to m_table1, m_table2, ... Which ones of those are *table names*? What are those other values, then?

Anyway: here's an example which shows how to do something like that - counting rows from tables. Try to adjust it to your situation, or - possibly - add some more info so that we'd know what you are doing.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    tname   sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
  3    l_cnt   number;
  4    l_str   varchar2(200);
  5  begin
  6    tname := sys.odcivarchar2list('EMP', 'DEPT');
  7
  8    for i in 1 .. tname.count loop
  9      l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || tname(i);
 10      execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 11      dbms_output.put_line(tname(i) ||': '|| l_cnt);
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
EMP: 14
DEPT: 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: added GROUP BY option]**

Here you go; as EMP and DEPT share the DEPTNO column, I chose it for a GROUP BY column.

```
SQL> declare
  2    tname   sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list();
  3    type    t_job is record (deptno varchar2(20), cnt number);
  4    type    t_tjob is table of t_job;
  5    l_tjob  t_tjob := t_tjob();
  6    l_str   varchar2(200);
  7  begin
  8    tname := sys.odcivarchar2list('EMP', 'DEPT');
  9
 10    for i in 1 .. tname.count loop
 11      l_str := 'select deptno, count(*) from ' || tname(i) ||' group by deptno';
 12      execute immediate l_str bulk collect into l_tjob;
 13
 14      for j in l_tjob.first .. l_tjob.last loop
 15        dbms_output.put_Line('Table ' || tname(i) || ': Deptno ' || l_tjob(j).deptno||
 16          ': number of rows = '|| l_tjob(j).cnt);
 17      end loop;
 18
 19    end loop;
 20  end;
 21  /
Table EMP: Deptno 30: number of rows = 6
Table EMP: Deptno 20: number of rows = 5
Table EMP: Deptno 10: number of rows = 3
Table DEPT: Deptno 10: number of rows = 1
Table DEPT: Deptno 20: number of rows = 1
Table DEPT: Deptno 30: number of rows = 1
Table DEPT: Deptno 40: number of rows = 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Group by *what*? Tables (usually) don't share column names. What would I group EMP by? And DEPT? Some other table? DEPT contains 3 columns - which one of them should be used in GROUP BY clause. EMP contains 8 columns. Which one of those should be used?

Comment: group by other column as I need to display number(count = l_cnt) and value(column), take please as exmaple one of column from EMP table

Comment: Yes, but **which other column**? For EMP table: EMPNO? ENAME? SAL? JOB? MGR? DEPTNO?

Comment: can be Job, it's doesn't matter as I just to want to see the syntax

Comment: OK, understood; it is the principle you're looking for. I edited my answer by adding the GROUP BY option. Have a look.

Comment: I have added also where from other loop and works great, thanks @Littlefoot

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this. Note that you can't run a simple select statement inside a PL/SQL without `INTO` clause. use a `refcursor` and `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`

```
DECLARE
   TYPE tables_names IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (30);

   TYPE selectTable IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (30);

   tName        tables_names;
   sTableName   selectTable;
   rc           SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   tName :=
      tables_names ('PERIOD',
                    'SETTING',
                    'RAP',
                    'LOG');
   sTableName :=
      selectTable ('m_table1',
                   'm_table2',
                   'm_table3',
                   'm_table4',
                   'm_table5');

   FOR i IN 1 .. tName.COUNT
   LOOP
      FOR j IN 1 .. sTableName.COUNT
      LOOP
         OPEN rc FOR
               'select col10, count(*) from '||USER||'.'
            || sTableName (j)
            || ' where table_name = '''
            || tName (i)
            || ''' group by col10';

         DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT (rc);

      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: it's possible to better format it? like one row by row?

Comment: @4est : I asked you in the comments to show the expected output in the question. Why don't you edit your question and say what exactly you want to see as output?

Comment: @4est : Unfortunately I can't load your images due to restrictions . However, I  think  the solution I gave you should work fine for getting the expected result. Please test and let me know if  you didn't

Comment: you can check my two select which I normally run to get the result, now I want to make it loop